# bash script to one liner

Tags: linux, bash, shell, mysql

My following is a bash script that I need to be able to run on one line

```
### Setup dump directory ###
BAKRSNROOT=/.snapshots/tmp

#####################################
### ----[ No Editing below ]------###
#####################################
### Default time format ###
TIME_FORMAT='%H_%M_%S%P'

### Make a backup ###
backup_mysql_rsnapshot(){
        local DBS="$($MYSQL -u $MUSER -h $MHOST -p$MPASS -Bse 'show databases')"
        local db="";
        [ ! -d $BAKRSNROOT ] && ${MKDIR} -p $BAKRSNROOT
        ${RM} -f $BAKRSNROOT/* >/dev/null 2>&1
#       [ $VERBOSE -eq 1 ] && echo "*** Dumping MySQL Database ***"
#       [ $VERBOSE -eq 1 ] && echo -n "Database> "
        for db in $DBS
        do
                local tTime=$(date +"${TIME_FORMAT}")
                local FILE="${BAKRSNROOT}/${db}.${tTime}.gz"
#               [ $VERBOSE -eq 1 ] && echo -n "$db.."
                ${MYSQLDUMP} --single-transaction -u ${MUSER} -h ${MHOST} -p${MPASS} $db | ${GZIP} -9 > $FILE
        done
#               [ $VERBOSE -eq 1 ] && echo ""
#               [ $VERBOSE -eq 1 ] && echo "*** Backup done [ files wrote to $BAKRSNROOT] ***"
}

### Die on demand with message ###
die(){
        echo "$@"
        exit 999
}
```

What I am confused about is can I just write:

```
DBS="$($MYSQL -u $MUSER -h $MHOST -p$MPASS -Bse 'show databases')"; for db in $DBS do mysqldump...morecode here
```

Or is that not possible? I need to be able to execute this in one line.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, you can do.

See my example:

```
~$ mysql -uroot -proot -Bse 'show databases'
information_schema
Company
UpdatedStructure
bd9199ce_7ccf_11e1_a561_3860779d10f7_db
checking
checkk
db_nagiosql_v32
demo
june14
mahi
midnms
mysql
```

Now I store this output in array:

```
:~$ mydbs="$(mysql -uroot -proot -Bse 'show databases')"
```

That is actually working :

```
:~$ for db in $mydbs; do echo $db;done;
information_schema
Company
UpdatedStructure
bd9199ce_7ccf_11e1_a561_3860779d10f7_db
checking
checkk
db_nagiosql_v32
demo
june14
mahi
midnms
mysql
```

In place of `for db in $mydbs; do echo "$db"; done;`  you can write like:

```
for db in $mydbs; do mysqldump -uroot -proot "$db" > "$db.sql" ; done;
```

**To do in one line**:

```
$ DBs="$(mysql -uroot -proot -Bse 'show databases')" ; for db in $DBs; do echo $db;done;
information_schema
Company
UpdatedStructure
bd9199ce_7ccf_11e1_a561_3860779d10f7_db
checking
checkk
db_nagiosql_v32
demo
june14
mahi
midnms
mysql
```

You can also do like this:

```
:~$ for db in $(mysql -uroot -proot -Bse 'show databases'); do echo $db; done;
```

Comment: You can tighten it a bit and get rid of the DBs variable: `for db in $(mysql ...); do ...; done` -- note, no quotes around `$(...)`

Comment: @glennjackman    Understood like this:  `for db in $(mysql -uroot -proot -Bse 'show databases'); do echo $db; done;`  --Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for a one-line for loop is:

`for asdf in blah; do something; done`

Note the additional semicolons.